# Performing Operations on a Subset Using Data Table

Tags: r, data.table, plyr, data-cleaning

I have a survey data set in wide form. For a particular question, a set of variables was created in the raw data to represent different the fact that the survey question was asked on a particular month.

I wish to create a new set of variables that have month-invariant names; the value of these variables will correspond to the value of a month-variant question for the month observed.

Please see an example / fictitious data set:

```
require(data.table)

data <- data.table(month = rep(c('may', 'jun', 'jul'),  each = 5),
                   may.q1 = rep(c('yes', 'no', 'yes'),  each = 5),
                   jun.q1 = rep(c('breakfast', 'lunch', 'dinner'),  each = 5),
                   jul.q1 = rep(c('oranges', 'apples', 'oranges'),  each = 5),
                   may.q2 = rep(c('econ', 'math', 'science'), each = 5),
                   jun.q2 = rep(c('sunny', 'foggy', 'cloudy'), each = 5),
                   jul.q2 = rep(c('no rain', 'light mist', 'heavy rain'), each = 5))
```

In this survey, there are really only two questions: "q1" and "q2". Each of these questions is repeatedly asked for several months. However, the observation contains a valid response only if the month observed in the data matches up with the survey question for a particular month.

For example: "may.q1" is observed as "yes" for any observation in "May". I would like a new "Q1" variable to represent "may.q1", "jun.q1", and "jul.q1". The value of "Q1" will take on the value of "may.q1" when the month is "may", and the value of "Q1" will take on the value of "jun.q1" when the month is "jun".

If I were to try and do this by hand using data table, I would want something like:

```
mdata <- data[month == 'may', c('month', 'may.q1', 'may.q2'), with = F]
setnames(mdata, names(mdata), gsub('may\\.', '', names(mdata)))
```

I would want this repeated "by = month".

If I were to use the "plyr" package for a data frame, I would solve using the following approach:

```
require(plyr)
data <- data.frame(data)

mdata <- ddply(data, .(month), function(dfmo) {
    dfmo <- dfmo[, c(1, grep(dfmo$month[1], names(dfmo)))]
    names(dfmo) <- gsub(paste0(dfmo$month[1], '\\.'), '', names(dfmo))
    return(dfmo)
})
```

Any help using a data.table method would be greatly appreciated, as my data are large. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A different way to illustrate :

```
data[, .SD[,paste0(month,c(".q1",".q2")), with=FALSE], by=month]

    month  may.q1     may.q2
 1:   may     yes       econ
 2:   may     yes       econ
 3:   may     yes       econ
 4:   may     yes       econ
 5:   may     yes       econ
 6:   jun   lunch      foggy
 7:   jun   lunch      foggy
 8:   jun   lunch      foggy
 9:   jun   lunch      foggy
10:   jun   lunch      foggy
11:   jul oranges heavy rain
12:   jul oranges heavy rain
13:   jul oranges heavy rain
14:   jul oranges heavy rain
15:   jul oranges heavy rain
```

But note the column names come from the first group (can rename afterwards using `setnames`). And it may not be the most efficient if there are a great number of columns with only a few needed. In that case Arun's solution melting to long format should be faster.

Comment: MatthewDowle, this is *definitely* faster than (my) melt + cast. I tried it out on a bigger data. Mine is no where close... It takes 23 seconds on a 1e5 * 100 columns whereas this does it in less than a second!

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** Seems very inefficient on bigger data. Check out @MatthewDowle's answer for a *really fast and neat* solution.

Here's a solution using `data.table`.

```
dd <- melt.dt(data, id.var=c("month"))[month == gsub("\\..*$", "", ind)][, 
        ind := gsub("^.*\\.", "", ind)][, split(values, ind), by=list(month)]
```

The function `melt.dt` is a small function (still more improvements to be made) I wrote to `melt` a `data.table` similar to that of the `melt` function in `plyr` (copy/paste this function shown below before trying out the code above).

```
melt.dt <- function(DT, id.var) {
    stopifnot(inherits(DT, "data.table"))
    measure.var <- setdiff(names(DT), id.var)
    ind <- rep.int(measure.var, rep.int(nrow(DT), length(measure.var)))
    m1  <- lapply(c("list", id.var), as.name)
    m2  <- as.call(lapply(c("factor", "ind"), as.name))
    m3  <- as.call(lapply(c("c", measure.var), as.name))    
    quoted <- as.call(c(m1, ind = m2, values = m3))
    DT[, eval(quoted)]
}
```

---

The idea: First melt the `data.table` with `id.var = month` column. Now, all your melted column names are of the form `month.question`. So, by removing ".question" from this melted column and equating with `month` column, we can remove all unnecessary entries. Once we did this, we don't need the "month." in the melted column "ind" anymore. So, we use `gsub` to remove "month." to retain just `q1, q2` etc.. After this, we have to `reshape` (or `cast`) it. This is done by grouping by `month` and splitting the `values` column by `ind` (which has either `q1` or `q2`. So, you'll get 2 columns for every month (which is then stitched together) to get your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this

```
data <- data.table(
                   may.q1 = rep(c('yes', 'no', 'yes'),  each = 5),
                   jun.q1 = rep(c('breakfast', 'lunch', 'dinner'),  each = 5),
                   jul.q1 = rep(c('oranges', 'apples', 'oranges'),  each = 5),
                   may.q2 = rep(c('econ', 'math', 'science'), each = 5),
                   jun.q2 = rep(c('sunny', 'foggy', 'cloudy'), each = 5),
                   jul.q2 = rep(c('no rain', 'light mist', 'heavy rain'), each = 5)
                   )


tmp <- reshape(data, direction = "long", varying = 1:6, sep = ".", timevar = "question")

str(tmp)
## Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':   30 obs. of  5 variables:
##  $ question: chr  "q1" "q1" "q1" "q1" ...
##  $ may     : chr  "yes" "yes" "yes" "yes" ...
##  $ jun     : chr  "breakfast" "breakfast" "breakfast" "breakfast" ...
##  $ jul     : chr  "oranges" "oranges" "oranges" "oranges" ...
##  $ id      : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

If you want to go further and melting this data again you can use the melt package

```
require(reshape2)
## remove the id column if you want (id is the last col so ncol(tmp))
res <- melt(tmp[,-ncol(tmp), with = FALSE], measure.vars = c("may", "jun", "jul"), value.name = "response", variable.name = "month")

str(res)
## 'data.frame':    90 obs. of  3 variables:
##  $ question: chr  "q1" "q1" "q1" "q1" ...
##  $ month   : Factor w/ 3 levels "may","jun","jul": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
##  $ response: chr  "yes" "yes" "yes" "yes" ...
```